# file transfer not working non media files in Android 11

Tags: ionic-framework, file-transfer, android-11, scoped-storage

file transfer not working non media files in Android 11(how handle scoped storage in ionic 3)

`var targetPath = this.file.externalDataDirectory+'ido/'+date.toISOString().split('T')[0]+'/'+name; this.fileTransfer.download(url, targetPath,true).then((entry) => { console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL()); });`